# All incoming channels must have the same format Parameter name: inputStreams.WaveFormat

Tags: naudio

I use NAudio. Before everything was good. But yesterday there was an error:

All incoming channels must have the same format
Parameter name: inputStreams.WaveFormat

mixer.AddInputStream(audio32);

I can't find a cause of error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inputs to the mixer must be of the same format. This means same sample rate, same bit depth and same number of channels (can't mix mono and stereo). Compare `mixer.WaveFormat.ToString()` and `audio32.WaveFormat.ToString()` and you will see what is different.